# How to get handle to active object MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

Im trying to create a calendar using MATLAB GUI.
I have two `Edit Text` objects - `edittext1` and `edittext2`.

I want to do this one:
I put cursor at `edittext1` then select date at calendar and it pits into text field of `edittext1`.
And the same for `edittext2`: if I put cursor into `edittext2` and select date it puts into `edittext2` Edit Text.

I know I can use callback for calendar this way.

**Question:**

How can I put into Callback function handler to ACTIVE edit text object?
How to get handle to object where cursor is now?

Comment: [Something like this](https://gist.github.com/sco1/60f0b4f54ab883c9e5d5f393b1c23db3) functions fine when run through the debugger, but for some reason I can't get it to work properly on its own. I hate Java...

Comment: @excaza Thank you very much! I try to simplify code to find mistake. See my edited question one more time pls.

Comment: @excaza I Decide to split the question for two parts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374942/function-works-only-in-debug-mode-matlab-gui

Comment: @excaza, I [modified your example](https://gist.github.com/Hokitlab/0c70f3e64d7da7d4bd7e553c760a23e0), it now works even in normal mode (just needed a `pause(0.1)` before fetching the java object property. (the other modifications are because I'm on R2013a so I don't have access to dot notation, I had to revert to the good old `set/get`).

Comment: This is breathtaking! @Hoki can you please explain it in detail? And I can't imagine how you find this solution... And you or excaza MUST write an answer here!

Comment: @excaza you or Hoki must write an answer!!

Comment: Well, my contribution was minor, it's kind of a small hack on top of @excaza's example, so I'll give him some time to write it as an answer by himself.

Comment: @Hoki by the way do you know about GUI object focusing (current question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the *focus* question, there is no *active* text box when you click a date on the java calendar, because the *active* component at this time **is** the java calendar.

To know which text box was active *last*, you simply need to keep track of it. One way is to add a callback to the edit box, which will update a variable (stored in the `appdata`) with the handle of the latest active text box.

Armed with that, the callback of the calendar will just retrieve the date, then place it in the *last active* text box.

Note: The `ButtonDownFcn` event of the text box will only fire on left **and** right click if the text box `'enable'` property is `'off'` or `'inactive'`. (if it is `'on'`, then only the right click is detected). That is why I declared the text boxes as `inactive`. That does not prevent you to update the text programmatically so I didn't think it was a problem.

---

Code for `testcalendar.m`:

```
function testcalendar
handles.f = figure;

commonEditProperties = {'Style', 'edit', 'String', '', ...
    'Units', 'Normalized', ...
    'Enable','inactive' , ...
    'callback',@EditBoxFcn , ...
    'ButtonDownFcn',@EditBoxFcn } ;

handles.ledit = uicontrol( commonEditProperties{:}, 'Position', [0.1 0.1 0.3 0.1], 'Tag','ledit'  );
handles.redit = uicontrol( commonEditProperties{:}, 'Position', [0.5 0.1 0.3 0.1], 'Tag','redit' );

% preallocate a variable to hold the active text box handle
setappdata(handles.f,'activeTextBox',[]) ;

com.mathworks.mwswing.MJUtilities.initJIDE;
% Put calendar to my figure
handles.jPanel = com.jidesoft.combobox.DateChooserPanel;
[handles.hPanel,handles.hContainer] = javacomponent(handles.jPanel,[100,100,200,200], handles.f);

juiFunHandle = handle(handles.jPanel, 'CallbackProperties');
set(juiFunHandle, 'MousePressedCallback', ...
   @(src, evnt)CellSelectionCallback(src, evnt, handles));
set(juiFunHandle, 'KeyPressedCallback', ...
   @(src, evnt)CellSelectionCallback(src, evnt, handles));

% store gui handles in application data
guidata(handles.f , handles)
end

function EditBoxFcn(hobj,~)
    handles = guidata(hobj) ;
    ActiveTextBox = get(hobj,'Tag') ;
    setappdata( handles.f , 'activeTextBox', handles.(ActiveTextBox) ) ;
end

function CellSelectionCallback(~, ~, handles)

    % retrieve the handle of the active text box
    ActiveTextBox = getappdata(handles.f,'activeTextBox') ;

    % assign a default active text box if none was selected before
    if isempty(ActiveTextBox) ; ActiveTextBox = handles.ledit ; end

    numRetry = 10 ;
    for k=1:numRetry
        pause(0.1)
        dateString = char( javaMethodEDT('getSelectedDate', handles.jPanel) ) ;
        if ~isempty(dateString) ; break ; end
    end

    set(ActiveTextBox , 'String' , dateString ) ;
end
```

---

See it in action:

[image: interactive calendar]

---

### Edit

There is no pure Matlab way to have your Matlab edit box fully editable **an** reacting (firing an event) to a single click of any mouse button.
You can get this functionality by using the text box underlying java object. This java object exposes a lot of events and you can just pick the one you need.

**The catch:**
To get the handle of the underlying java object, you need to use the almighty `findjobj` utility by *Yair Altman*. You can download the latest version from the file exchange here: [findjobj](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects)

Once you have that saved in your Matlab path, just replace the few first line of code defining the edit boxes given in the example above by:

```
commonEditProperties = {'Style', 'edit', 'String', '', 'Units', 'Normalized', 'Enable','on' } ;

handles.ledit = uicontrol( commonEditProperties{:}, 'Position', [0.1 0.1 0.3 0.1] );
handles.redit = uicontrol( commonEditProperties{:}, 'Position', [0.5 0.1 0.3 0.1] );
% preallocate a variable to hold the active text box handle
setappdata(handles.f,'activeTextBox',[]) ;

% Find the java underlying object for the text boxes
ledit = findjobj(handles.ledit) ;
redit = findjobj(handles.redit) ;
% assign a callback to the java object (which CAN detect single click)
set(ledit,'MouseClickedCallback',@(h,e) setappdata( handles.f , 'activeTextBox', handles.ledit ) ) ;
set(redit,'MouseClickedCallback',@(h,e) setappdata( handles.f , 'activeTextBox', handles.redit ) ) ;
```

And you can completely comment or remove the sub-function `EditBoxFcn` as the callback action is done directly.

Comment: Hoki, thank you very much.
I decide use 'inactive' mode, because let user to change some data by his hands - is a bad way.
But still it's interesting - is it possible to do for 'on' mode?
It works but has 1 problem - it needs data in Editbox must be changed! If I put cursor without changing data than program continue to put data into last CHANGED editbox!

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam. I know, the `inactive` mode is the only one where the pure Matlab callback can be fired on a single click in the text box (without any modification of the content). If you want the text box to be editable **and** reactive to a single click, you'll have to use the event fired by the text box underlying java object (so it will be more _undocumented_ code). I'll edit the answer to add that.

Comment: thank you! By the way: why do you use `setappdata/loadappdata`? Can I use `handles.ActiveTextBox` ?

Comment: yes you could just use the `handles` structure to store your "last active" text box handle. Just a matter of choice. In general, I use the `handles` structure to store only the handles of my GUI components, and I use `appdata` to store anything else I need to save. Bottom line, both ways could work (even some other ways exist). Read the documentation article to see the pros and cons of each method: [Passing Data Around your User Interface](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/2883/matlab-user-interfaces/9775/passing-data-around-your-user-interface#t=201611031511409700029)