# Function works only in Debug Mode MATLAB GUI

Tags: java, matlab, user-interface, debugging, matlab-guide

I'm trying to create a calendar using MATLAB GUI.
I found [this tutorial](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/date-selection-components) and created calendar:

```
com.mathworks.mwswing.MJUtilities.initJIDE;
% Put calendar to my figure
jPanel = com.jidesoft.combobox.DateChooserPanel;
[hPanel,hContainer] = javacomponent(jPanel,[500,130,200,200],gcf);

set(handles.hPanel, 'MousePressedCallback', ...
   @(src, evnt)CellSelectionCallback(src, evnt, handles));
set(handles.hPanel, 'KeyPressedCallback', ...
   @(src, evnt)CellSelectionCallback(src, evnt, handles));
```

Also I have Edit Text object. Lets try to put Selected Value to it!
I use [excaza's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363256/put-selected-date-from-jude-into-edit-text-object-matlab-gui#comment67983133_40363256):

```
function CellSelectionCallback(hObject, evnt, handles)
hModel = handle(hObject.getSelectionModel, 'CallbackProperties');
selectedDate = hModel.getSelectedDate();
dayNumber = get(selectedDate,'Date');
handles.edit_start.String = num2str(dayNumber); 

handles.newNote(3) = {dayNumber};
guidata(handles.figure1, handles);
```

So I can read selected date and put it anywhere.

**Problem**

Code works only in Debug Mode. In normal mode my Edit Text Object (edit_start) stays empty!

Comment: `Java` and `Matlab` do talk together but timing issues appear everywhere when you mix both component types in your code. For your case, just adding `pause(0.1)` before you fetch the java calendar object property (so before `selectedDate = hModel.getSelectedDate();`) works fine (in debug mode, Matlab has plenty of time to fetch that, in normal run mode, you need to leave enough time for it manually).

Comment: @Hoki yep, you are right, that was the problem! If you write it as answer I will accept it!